# error in trigger creation in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I created the very simple triger and I think syntex is also correct:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER trig1 after INSERT ON urlcontent for each row
BEGIN
    insert into userpost(userid,url,hash) values (userid,url,hash);
END;
```

gives error:

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3`

Structure of both table:

```
CREATE TABLE urlcontent (
  userid text NOT NULL,
  url varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `desc` varchar(2048) NOT NULL,
  preview varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  img_url varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  title varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `hash` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  rate varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  sentiment varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`hash`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table 'userpost'
--

CREATE TABLE userpost (
  userid varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  url varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `desc` varchar(2048) DEFAULT NULL,
  preview varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  img_url varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  title varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hash` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  rate varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  pcount varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  ncount varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  isset varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  sentiment varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (userid,`hash`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

hash and url are key in userpost table/

**Structure of both table**

Comment: are the values userid,url,hash originated from urlcontent?

Comment: values are coming from user, like in registration table. I mean user insert these values into urlcontent. And on insert I want same to be inserted into userpost table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your specific error is likely due to the delimiter being defined as `;`.

If you change the delimiter to `|` (in the box below the query editor) like in the following image it will work:

[image]

This helps the trigger to be created without stoping the query at the first `;`.

This would work, but to insert the values from `urlcontent` into `userpost` you have to add the keywords NEW before the values. This tells the trigger that the values you want to insert in `userpost` are the ones that were just inserted into `urlcontent`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig1 AFTER INSERT ON urlcontent 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    insert into userpost(userid,url,hash) values (NEW.userid,NEW.url,NEW.hash);
END;
|
```

Comment: did you change the delimiter to |? i tested it here and it worked

Comment: yes, but first you have to change the delimiter to | in the box below the query box, like in this example: http://i.imgur.com/zrf6fbK.png

Comment: Thanks for image. Worked as expected